# How can I deterministically detect the shader fragment location in its 2x2 pixel quad?

Tags: glsl, shader, gpu, hlsl, cg

I've been trying to utilize the techniques in Eric Penner's "Shader Amortization using
Pixel Quad Message Passing" from GPU Pro 2, Chapter VI.2.  The basic idea is that modern GPU's process fragment shaders in 2x2 fragment quads, and you can use ddx() and ddy() to get the value of some_var at all four fragments as long as the following hold:

1. Your GPU supports high-quality derivatives
2. You know which fragment you're processing (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right)

This opens up a lot of opportunities for fragment shader optimization (like distributing texture fetches over a 2x2 pixel quad) that you'd need Compute Shaders to beat.

My problem is this:
I can't deterministically detect which fragment I'm processing.  Ideally, each fragment block would start at even-numbered output pixel coords like (0, 0), (2, 0), ... (1024, 1024), ..., so you'd just need to check whether the output pixel x and y coords are even or odd to know which fragment you're currently processing.  The method Penner uses in the book assumes this works...but it seems to be going wrong for me.

Unfortunately, my 2x2 fragment quads appear to be starting in nondeterministic places: I've seen them start at (even, even), (even, odd), and (odd, even).  I can't remember if I've seen (odd, odd) or not, but anyway, the arrangement seems to depend on a myriad of factors I don't understand, including the output resolution and shader specifics.  (I'm testing on an 8800 GTS, in case anyone's wondering.)

Does anyone know what might be causing this nondeterminism or have any documentation on it?  I understand there's virtually no official standardization in this area, but I'm more interested in how things work in practice on modern desktop-level GPU's, and I'm hoping there's a way to get this technique to work.  If no one knows how to reason about the even/odd start behavior, does anyone know any other way of determining the current fragment's relative location in its 2x2 quad?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the premise of my question was mostly wrong:
The 2x2 fragment quads DO almost always start on even pixel numbers...as long as the output resolution is even-numbered.

If the output resolution is odd-numbered (a possibility with the underlying program I'm working with), things can get more complicated, for obvious reasons.  I don't expect there's any uniformity here across drivers/GPU's/etc. either, but my current tests (which themselves may still be buggy) appear to demonstrate 2x2 pixel quads starting at an odd pixel along the dimension with odd resolution, at least when the odd dimension is horizontal.

All of this weirdness helped obscure my bigger issue: The code I used to detect the fragment's location in the pixel quad was buggy.  I tested by setting the texture coordinates equal within a pixel quad (set to the pixel quad center)...or so I thought.  However, I calculated the screen coordinates based on a full-screen quad where the uv mapping has the +v axis pointing downward.  The screenspace origin starts at the bottom-left, because it's based on the top-right quadrant of Cartesian coordinates, and I accidentally forgot to invert the v-coordinate of the uv offset I used to find the pixel quad center.  Many of my nondeterministic observations came from failing to check my assumptions while debugging and misinterpreting things as a result, particularly in combination with odd resolutions.

This was an embarrassing mistake I should have caught a lot sooner, but I figured I'd detail it as a warning to others to always double-check the direction of your vertical axis when you're dealing with opposite-facing coordinate frames. ;)

UPDATE:
I ran across a situation where 2x2 pixel quads started on even pixel numbers even when the resolution was odd.  Thanks to the nondeterminism under odd resolutions, I had to work out another solution:

1. If you're deriving your screen pixel numbers from the uv coords of a fullscreen quad (for post-processing), the fragment location derived from this is only useful for arranging/placing shared samples between fragments, etc., not for the quad-pixel communication itself.  You'll need to have screen pixel numbers with respect to the screenspace origin for that.  You can derive these from vertex positions, or you can use ddx().x and ddy().y on the uv-based pixel numbers to find out their screen direction and mirror the fragment position in the appropriate direction from there.
2. Calculate the fragment location based on your screen pixel numbers (with respect to the true screenspace origin) and the assumption 2x2 pixel quads start on even pixels.  (If you used uv-based pixel numbers, now is the time to mirror things.)
3. Do a ddx().x and ddy().y on the fragment location, and if they're negative in either direction, you know the pixel quad starts at an odd pixel number in that direction...so mirror in that direction.
4. If you calculate two fragment positions, one based on a uv origin and one based on a screen origin, use the uv-based one for reasoning about uv-based sample placement, and use the screen-based one for actually obtaining the values of a variable at neighboring fragments.
5. Profit.

I'll post a link to my working MIT-licensed code once I release it on Github, along with usage examples (the speedup is unfortunately not what I expected, but whatever ;)).  I'm just waiting to get done with a larger shader I'll be uploading along with it.

Comment: It's been several years, but I have to revisit this for work, and I noticed I hadn't yet posted a link.  A link to my working quad-pixel communication code is here (Cg code, but easily convertible to HLSL): https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/blob/01c80d20ddfa2ca25c1340b5beb72866c606f88c/include/quad-pixel-communication.h

Comment: Also, I should clarify some things: 1. I was writing .cg shaders for OpenGL at the time, which is why the screen coords started in the top-left.  Some of this is not relevant for HLSL in Direct3D, where screen coords (SV_POSITION) start in the top-left.  2. In step '2' above, the "fragment location" I'm referring to is the pixel's current location within its 2x2 quad, in ([-1, 1], [-1, 1]) IIRC.  I'm a bit rusty now (hence the revisit), but hopefully this helps anyone else with similar issues.

Comment: The link above was more opaque than it should be.  Here's a better one: https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/blob/master/include/quad-pixel-communication.h